# How to achieve fluid width, equally spaced divs in a gallery style?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to achieve a div alignment scenario. I'm relatively new to css, but I've been digging into it quite a lot lately and aligning elements is at times infuriating, to put it mildly.

I have a div container filling the page. Within this container, there is a collection of fixed width/height divs (a lot of them). It's essentially an image gallery, but the images are background images of the divs, so I can overlay some other content if I need to. The divs are inline-block, so they populate the parent container left to right until a div can't fit into the available space left. They then continue on the next "row", and so on. The problem is that this results (or can result) in a chunk of empty space at the end of each row.

I'd like the divs in each row to be equally spaced, but the number of divs in each row should **not** be fixed. I'd like the number of divs in a row to adapt to different screen resolutions (or screen resizing), but remain equally spaced. The last row may also be a problem, since if the divs don't fill it, then I'd like each one to vertically align with the one above, not stretch to fill the row.

Here's an example of what it looks like now. You can see the gap at the end of the first row that I want to avoid.

[image: Div Alignment Problem]

I can use the latest version of jQuery and jQuery UI. For what it's worth, IE <9 is not a concern for me.

I know that fluidly spaced divs horizontally is a common enough problem, but any tutorials and tips that I've found require you to know how many divs should be in row, and also that the divs do not break onto a new row.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check this out: http://codepen.io/patrickkunka/pen/GECBF

Comment: It isn't widely supported, yet... but you might also look into the flex-box layout... http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

I actually decided to go with using an unordered list as the container with the list items holding the divs, so I can take advangtage of justifying the list items.

More details here: [Why does horizontal list item justification not work with dynamically added items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393557/why-does-horizontal-list-item-justification-not-work-with-dynamically-added-item/18393652?noredirect=1#18393652)