# Why does horizontal list item justification not work with dynamically added items

Tags: javascript, css, html, html-lists

I'm creating a grid of divs, and I decided to use an unordered list as the container, so that I can take advantage of horizontally justifying the list items that will contain the divs. The problem is that the justification only works with the HTML written in advance of the page load. If I try to create and add the list items dynamically with Javascript, the justification fails.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kQNNe/) demonstrates the problem with two unordered lists, where one is populated statically (succeeds) and the other dynamically (fails).

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><div></div></li>
    <li><div></div></li>
    <li><div></div></li>
</ul>

<ul id="list"></ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
var list = document.getElementById("list");
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    li.appendChild(div);
    list.appendChild(li);  
}
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: justify;
}
ul:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
li {
    display: inline;
}
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #4391EE;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principal difference between the static version and the dynamic version is that the static version has whitespace between each element.

To fix the dynamic version, you need to also append some whitespace:

```
list.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/kQNNe/1/

Comment: [Here's a fiddle showing the difference without JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/kQNNe/2/)